# Adding default --Select-- option result array in wordpress

Tags: php, function, html-select

In below function get_brand() I want to add on first row the text: --Select--.
My idea was to use array_merge. But I get an empty row extra on top to all the options.

What do I have to do to get the text: --Select-- at top?

```
function get_brand() {
global $wpdb;

    $brand_array = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT  brand  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "automatten GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand ASC");
    $select = array("brand" => '--Select--'); 
    $result = array_merge($select, $brand_array);
return $result;
}
```

Result is:

> Array ( [brand] => --Select-- [0] => stdClass Object ( [brand] =>
>   AIXAM ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [brand] => Alfa ) [2] => stdClass
>   Object ( [brand] => AMC ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [brand] => Artega )

Comment: see result list. it is filled so not empty

Comment: The values from the database are objects, rather than arrays. Try making `$select` an array containing a `stdClass` object where the `brand` property has a value of `--Select--`.

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is in `stdClass` format, so make an object same as your result, create array of that class and then use array_merge like,

```
$brand_array = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT  brand  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "automatten GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand ASC");
$brand = new stdClass; // create a new object here
$brand->brand = '--Select--'; // assign Select here
$result = array_merge(array($brand), $brand_array); // now use array merge
```

Comment: Correct solution! Thanks.

Comment: Great, put a tick mark so that other users can get help from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are `type-casting` an `array` to an `object`.

**Change this to:**

```
array_merge($select, $brand_array);
```

**This:**

```
array_merge((object)$select, $brand_array);
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$select = array("brand" => '--Select--');

function get_brand()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $brand_array = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT  brand  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "automatten GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand ASC");
    $select = array("brand" => '--Select--');
    $result = array_merge((object)$select, $brand_array);
    return $result;
}
```